# Postgres: Select a composite field with each field name as a value?

Tags: postgresql

I have a composite field called "Address". It has fields:
 - street_name
 - street_number
 - area

If I do a normal select:

```
select address from mytable where id = 1
```

I get:

```
address => ("my street",1,earth)
```

I want a way to select this and get:

```
street_name => my street
street_number => 1
area => earth
```

I managed to get it right in the past doing something like this:

```
select address.* from mytable where id = 1
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas how to get the result the way I want?

Comment: You want every element of the composite one different row? or all of then can be at same row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rowtypes.html). If you're trying to reference the subfields of a composite type you need to put the name in parentheses, otherwise the parser thinks you're trying to get something from the 'address' table

```
SELECT (address).* from mytable where id = 1
```

Comment: this should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to select the elements do as this:

```
select address.street_name, 
       address.street_number, 
       address.area 
  from mytable where id = 1
```

if you want the result exact as your question:

```
    select 'street_name =>' || address.street_name 
     from mytable where id = 1 union
    select 'street_number =>' || address.street_number 
     from mytable where id = 1 union
    select 'area=>' || address.area 
     from mytable where id = 1
```